# Sometimes $_COOKIE[] empty after cookie set and cookie present in browser but after two three page reload it works perfectly

Tags: php, cookies

I have an issue regarding php $_COOKIE[] it gives empty but cookie is set in browser and it has value also but still $_COOKIE[] gives empty sometimes but it works after two three reload it gives value. I can't find out what is the actual issue. No caching problem is there, size of cookie is 1920bytes.

Comment: Could you add code and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This helps us answer your question better.

Comment: Also by "set in browser", do you mean in javascript or some other front-end code?

Comment: @Chipster I mentioned it this code in php.

Comment: @Chipster here i set cookie setcookie('benefit', json_encode($form_data),$time ,'/');
$form_data this is an array
and on other url when i reload and get cookie data sometimes it gives me null and after sometime or 2-3 page reload it works.

$data = json_decode($_COOKIE['benefit']);
this is get cookie data code on other url.

Comment: So PHP is setting the cookie. Okay got you. Could you still edit your question to post more relevant code? `setcookie()` alone is enough context. How are those parameters generated, and where do you try to read `$_COOKIE[]`?

Comment: @Chipster check above comment

Comment: Can you edit you question and add the code there, though? It will help us help you.

Comment: @Chipster I think the issue in server because it perfectly works on localhost but not on other server.